# Load route with a jquery load method

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I wanna to load a router with jquery

Here is my route

```
Route::post('/loadmore',[
    'as' => 'loadmore',
    'uses' => 'PostCnt@loadComment'
]);
```

controller

```
public function loadComment()
{
    return view('comment');
}
```

I want to load the router by jquery load method.In home page i created a div where route will be loaded here is my home and jquery code.

home page div

```
<div class="loadingcomment">

</div>
```

and jquery

```
var urlLoadmore   =  '{{ route('loadmore') }}';
$(".loadingcomment").load(urlLoadmore);
```

Above code is not working how can i solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generate JS code with PHP, that's a terrible practice. Just use route URL instead of route name in the `load()` function:

```
var urlLoadmore   =  'user/profile';
$(".loadingcomment").load(urlLoadmore);
```

Comment: thanks..change done but it's actually didnot laod the view page content.

Comment: @nuralam, `load()` function loads content with AJAX. If you just want to redirect user to some URL, do something like `window.location.href = 'user/profile';`

Comment: @ Alexey Mezenin ok i am trying.

Answer (score 0):

`jquery.load()` function make a **GET** request to server, but your route waiting for **POST**. So you just need to change your route for solve your issue:

```
Route::get('/loadmore',[
    'as' => 'loadmore',
    'uses' => 'PostCnt@loadComment'
]);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.